# how to map data based on another vector in R

Tags: r

I have the dataset (pts) like this:

```
x <- seq(-124.25,length=115,by=0.5)    
y <- seq(26.25,length=46,by=0.5)
z <- 1:5290

longlat <- expand.grid(x = x, y = y)
pts <- data.frame(longlat,z) 
names(pts) <- c( "lon","lat","data")
```

I knew that I can map the dataframe (pts） into a map by doing:

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(maps)
coordinates(pts)=~x+y

proj4string(pts)=CRS("+init=epsg:4326") # set it to long, lat

pts = spTransform(pts,CRS(" +init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0"))
pts <- as(pts, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame")
r = raster(pts)
projection(r) = CRS(" +init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0")

plot(r)
map("usa",add=T)
```

If I have one more factor "class"

```
pts$class=rep(1:5,1058)
```

How can I add the information of "class" so that I can have 5 sets of mono-color schemes on the same map?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by mapping data?

Comment: I think having 5 different color schemes in one plot is a really bad idea. Maybe if you could explain in more detail what you need, we could offer some advice/alternatives.

Comment: Is there a way to do this kind of thing, even if it is a bad idea?